# How to display duplicates objects in a queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model `Stock` and I'm trying to find duplicates in db. When I do the filter `Stock.objects.filter(component__in=components)`, I expect to see duplicates, but this filter excludes dups, but I need to display all of them.

For example: my list of components is:

```
1
2
3
  1 (this ones are subcomponents of components but I can convert it to component objects)
  2 (this ones are subcomponents of components but I can convert it to component objects)
  3 (this ones are subcomponents of components but I can convert it to component objects)
4
5
6
etc.
```

Here comes my problem, in the filter, it deletes the 1, 2 and 3 objects under the first 3 object because it has the same ID, but I want to display them all.

```
def get_custom_queryset(self):
        params = {}
        reference = False
        for param in iter(self.request.GET):
            if param.startswith('Search_'):
                search = param[7:]                
                if search == 'inventory':
                    try:
                        inventory = self.request.GET[param]
                        if inventory == 'on':
                            components, stock_codes = [], []
                            stock = Stock.objects.filter(is_inventory=True) # Cannot be first() because in self.table it requires a queryset instead of a list
                            for s in stock:
                                stock_codes.append(s.component.code)
                            components_on_inventory = Component.objects.filter(code__in=stock_codes)
                            for coi in components_on_inventory:
                                if coi.has_subcomponents():
                                    qs_sc = []
                                    components.append(coi)
                                    for sc in coi.subcomponents():
                                        qs_sc.append(sc.subcomponent)
                                    components.append(qs_sc)
                                else:
                                    components.append(coi)
                            i = 0
                            while i < len(components):
                                if isinstance(components[i], list):
                                    sc_list = components[i]
                                    components = components[:i] + sc_list + components[i+1:]
                                i += 1
                            queryset = Stock.objects.filter(component__in=components)
                            if queryset.filter(is_inventory=False).exists(): # Happens that in Stock QuerySet appears automatically components that are not inventory, so we delete it if existing
                                queryset.filter(is_inventory=False).delete()
                            self.queryset = queryset
                            reference = True
                            break
                    except:
                        pass
```

I tried to fix it with no lock. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and see [ask]

Comment: Could you share your Stock and Component models ?